# Meshes imported into Unity into Blender always corrupt

Tags: unity, blender, models, terrain, mesh

I want to import a terrain mesh I made in Blender into Unity, however Unity seems to fail to load it correctly. What could be the reason behind this and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: (╯°□°）╯︵ sןɐɯɹou

Comment: @AlexM. Thanks for the laugh! I'm new to 3D modeling, wasn't aware about what normals are. Now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

(╯°□°）╯︵ sןɐɯɹou

As per the comments, I'll repost this as an answer, so that the question has some closure.

That means you will have to recalculate your normals. Edit mode, <kbd>A</kbd> to select all of the faces, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals (outside).